# go to link on button click - jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic-data, response.redirect

I have a script as below

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
    document.location.href=$(this).attr('id');
});
```

the button1 has variable unique ids. on click, the page must redirect to url "`www.example.com/index.php?id=buttonid`" but now the page is redirecting only to "`button id`".

I want to add the string "`www.example.com/index.php?id=`" before the current url. How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
   window.location = "www.example.com/index.php?id=" + this.id;
});
```

First of all using `window.location` is better as according to specification `document.location` value was read-only and might cause you headaches in older/different browsers. Check notes @[MDC DOM document.location page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location)

And for the second - using `attr` jQuery method to get id is a bad practice - you should use direct native DOM accessor `this.id` as the value assigned to `this` is normal DOM element.

Comment: +1 for being the first to suggest window.location and this.id, I went with my answer quickly without them ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
   document.location.href='/index.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the domain:

```
 $('.button1').click(function() {
   window.location = 'www.example.com/index.php?id=' + this.id;
 });
```

Comment: href is unnecessary and look at my answer to see more info on things that could have been done better

Comment: @Tom Tu: Yeah good suggestion, updated the code. You need to consider the down vote, it wasn't wrong any way.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just change the second line to

```
document.location.href="www.example.com/index.php?id=" + $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: @blasteralfred Check my answer for some more tips and good practices

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current url with `window.location.href` but I think you will need the jQuery query plugin to manipulate the query string: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object