# Get Django API data from a non-static url using Ajax-Jquery [Without REST Framework]

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-urls

In my server-side app created with Django, I need to show articles based on the url, which contains year, month and user_id of articles.
*blog/1/2022/8* should shows all articles of august.

In client-side app (Jquery), I have to call an API which returns all articles filtered by year and month.

**How can I set the url in ajax with the variable informations of year and month?**

urls.py (I have to use these urlpatterns):

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    #link to API
    path('API/<int:user_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>', views.get_articles, name='get_articles'),
    
    #link to html file
    path('<int:user_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Article(models.Model):
    author =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_year(self):
        return self.pub_date.year

    def get_month(self):
        return self.pub_date.month
```

Views:

```
def index(request, **kwargs):
    return render(request, template_name='blog/index.html', context={'user_id':kwargs.get('user_id')})

#return json data with articles filtered by year and month of url
def get_articles(request, **kwargs):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(
        pub_date__year = kwargs.get('year'),
        pub_date__month = kwargs.get('month'),
    ).values('title','author','pub_date')

    data = {
        'articles' : list(articles)
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

index.html:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <br><h3>Articoli</h3>
    
    <div id="article_list"></div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

blog.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: WHICH URL?,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                var item = $('<p>ID: '+ data[i].id +'<br>Titolo: '+ data[i].title +'<br>Autore: ' +
                    data[i].author  + '<br>Data: ' + data[i].pub_date +'</p>');
                $('#article_list').append(item);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Bonus question:** I should serialize data used by API, but How can I do without rest_framework?

If you are wondering why without REST Framework, It's for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution, after the contribution of Mathews Musukuma in answers.

urls.py

```
#link to html files
path('<int:user_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>', views.index, name='index'),
#link to api
path('api/blog/<int:user_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>', views.get_articles, name='get_articles'),
```

I edited the view *get_article()* which creates the JSON file with objects.
The `is_ajax()` method suggested is deprecated, so I overwrote it like this:

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

def get_articles(request, **kwargs):
    if is_ajax(request=request):
        articles = Article.objects.filter(
            pub_date__year = kwargs.get('year'),
            pub_date__month = kwargs.get('month'),
        ).values('id','title','author','pub_date')

        data = {
            'articles': list(articles),
            'path_info': {
                    'month': kwargs.get('month'),
                    'year': kwargs.get('year'),
                    'user_id': kwargs.get('user_id'),
            }   
        }
        
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

In jquery I used `window.location` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944460/16057975) to get the current url. So I edited it to match the correct url of api.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $url = window.location.pathname
    $url_api = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'+$url
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: $url_api,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
           ...
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clean the urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    # API url
    path('api/<int:author_id>/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.get_articles, name='get_articles'),
    
    # view url
    path('<int:user_id>/', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

For your API view, you can use check if request is `request.is_ajax()` then do something within the if statement block.

```
def get_articles(request, author_id, year, month):
    if request.is_ajax():
        articles = Article.objects.filter(
            author_id=author_id,
            pub_date__year=year,
            pub_date__month=month,
        ) 

        data = {
            'articles' : list(articles)
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Now you can use the api endpoint with AJAX as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: `localhost:8000/api/${1}/${2022}/${8}/`,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
            for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                var item = $('<p>ID: '+ data[i].id +'<br>Titolo: '+ data[i].title +'<br>Autore: ' +
                    data[i].author  + '<br>Data: ' + data[i].pub_date +'</p>');
                $('#article_list').append(item);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I asked without using rest framework. It's possible? Can you explain How `localhost:8000/api/${1}/${2022}/${8}/` works?

Comment: I have updated the code to use `request.is_ajax()`. Thanks